# How to keep the number of errors and text errors in SSIS?

Tags: error-handling, ssis, sql-server-2014

This is my SSIS package, and these are the requirements that have to do but i not know how:

At the level of the package is necessary to preserve the number of errors.
At the level of task too, with the difference that if there is an error it is necessary to preserve the text of errors.
At the level of data flow (sub-task) is necessary to preserve the text of errors.

Does anyone have an idea?
[SSIS package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihwd9.png)

Comment: We need a bit more information. How do you want to preserve the number of errors? And what exacty is an error? (I guess you mean all records with no match output?)

Comment: At any way, I just think I should have one task for it. I think of any errors that may occur when transferring data from the source to the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add package-level variables for storing the count of errors, and the text of errors, and populate them in the OnError event handlers of all your tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think this could help me. I am new in SSIS, and would you be able to with a little
more details to tell me how to do that in the event handler? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a broader question, and there are already lots of articles on the internet that go into detail.  Google for articles on SSIS error handling and event handlers, and you will find plenty of good information.